# FEM: elastic cylinder under circumferential pressure

Tags: finite-element-method, solidmechanics

Suppose you have an elastic cylinder of radius $R$ and height $H$ and you want to solve the mechanical 3D equilibrium with Mathematica's FEM.

**How do you impose a pressure $p$ only on the cylinder sides at $r=R$ (only on the sides, *not* on the top)?**

If possible, I would prefer to stay in the description with Cartesian coordinates.

[image: Cylinder mesh]

I am well aware, that a simple analytical solution is easily computable ($u_r(r) = a r + b/r$) for the isotropic case, but I want to extend this problem to some other cases with anisotropic materials and more stuff.

--

**Working example with pressure on top**

Parameters: geometry, loading and material

```
(*Geometry [m]*)
R = 1;
H = 5;

(*Pressure [N]*)
p = 10000;

(*Material*)
Em = 2.1*10^9;(*Young's modulus [N/m^2]*)
nu = 0.3;(*Poisson's ratio [-]*)
```

FEM setup:

Geometry

```
region = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, H}}, R];
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1.0, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
Show[mesh["Wireframe"], Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, x3}]
```

Material (full fourth-order stiffness tensor $\mathbb{C}$ for isotropic material with given Young's modulus `Em` and Poisson's ratio `nu`, see parameters)

```
(*Isotropic material stiffness-fourth-order tensor*)
(*Identities*)
I2 = IdentityMatrix@3;
IdI = TensorProduct[I2, I2];
I4 = TensorTranspose[IdI, {1, 3, 2, 4}];
IS = (I4 + TensorTranspose[I4, {1, 2, 4, 3}])/2;
(*Isotropic projectors*)
P1 = 1/3*IdI;
P2 = IS - P1;
(*Isotropic stiffness*)
C4 = l1*P1 + l2*P2;
l1 = 3*Km;
l2 = 2*Gm;
Km = 1/3*Em/(1 - 2*nu);
Gm = 1/2*Em/(1 + nu);
```

PDE: linear momentum without body forces ($\mathrm{div}(\boldsymbol{\sigma}) = (0,0,0)_{\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}}$ with $\sigma_{ij} = C_{ijkl} u_{k,l}$)

```
pde = Table[
   Inactive[
      Div][-C4[[i, ;; , 1, ;;]].Inactive[Grad][
        u1[x1, x2, x3], {x1, x2, x3}], {x1, x2, x3}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][-C4[[i, ;; , 2, ;;]].Inactive[Grad][
        u2[x1, x2, x3], {x1, x2, x3}], {x1, x2, x3}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][-C4[[i, ;; , 3, ;;]].Inactive[Grad][
        u3[x1, x2, x3], {x1, x2, x3}], {x1, x2, x3}]
   , {i, 3}
   ];
```

BCs: Dirichlet to fix bottom ($x_3=0$) and Neumann to impose pressure $p$ on top ($x_3 = H$)

```
bcD = {
   DirichletCondition[{u3[x1, x2, x3] == 0}, x3 == 0],
   DirichletCondition[{u1[x1, x2, x3] == 0, u2[x1, x2, x3] == 0, 
     u3[x1, x2, x3] == 0}, x1 == 0 && x2 == 0 && x3 == 0]
   };
bcN = {0, 0, NeumannValue[-p, x3 == H]};
```

Solution for top pressure

```
{u1sol, u2sol, u3sol} = 
   NDSolveValue[{pde == bcN, bcD}, {u1, u2, u3}, 
    Element[{x1, x2, x3}, mesh]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.374435, Null}

Plot deformation

```
mesh = u1sol["ElementMesh"];
Show[{mesh["Wireframe"], 
  ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {u1sol, u2sol, u3sol}, 
    "ScalingFactor" -> 10^5][
   "Wireframe"[
    "ElementMeshDirective" -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]},
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, x3}]
```

[image: Deformed]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
pred = (0 <= x3 <= H) && (x1^2 + x2^2 >= (R^2 - 10^-2));
bcN = {NeumannValue[-p*Cos[ArcTan[x1, x2]], pred], 
   NeumannValue[-p*Sin[ArcTan[x1, x2]], pred], 0};
```

Note, that you have to restrict the bcN at the cabs such that there is not force on them. The -10^-2 is for the quadratic case.

A much simpler approach is to use boundary element `ElementMarker`.

I generated a mesh with:

```
region = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, H}}, R];
mesh = ToElementMesh[region, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1.0, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1, "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "OpenCascde"];
groups = mesh["BoundaryElementMarkerUnion"];
temp = Most[Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[groups])]];
colors = ColorData["BrightBands"][#] & /@ temp;
Show[
 mesh["Edgeframe"],
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements", 
   "MeshElementStyle" -> (Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[#]] & /@ 
      colors)]]
 , Epilog -> Inset[LineLegend[colors, groups], Scaled[{0.85, 0.8}]]
 ]
```

[image]

This now has an `ElementMarker` 3 at the boundary in question.

```
bcN = {NeumannValue[-p*Cos[ArcTan[x1, x2]], ElementMarker == 3], 
   NeumannValue[-p*Sin[ArcTan[x1, x2]], ElementMarker == 3], 0};
```

Also consider using the `"OpenCascade"` boundary mesh generator. That will improve the quality of the meshed geometry.

```
ToElementMesh[region, "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> "OpenCascde"]
```

This will be the default from V12.3 onward.

This will give you:

[image]

Comment: Cool, thank you. This is numerically interesting, if you use `0 <= x3 <= H` instead, the amplified deformation is quite different at the top and bottom. I suppose that is due to internal numerical reasons, right?

Comment: I think it's more of a modeling issue in relation to the DirichletCondition to constraint the object. For this `bcD = {
      DirichletCondition[{u1[x1, x2, x3] == 0, u2[x1, x2, x3] == 0, 
     u3[x1, x2, x3] == 0}, x3 == 0],
   DirichletCondition[{u1[x1, x2, x3] == 0, u2[x1, x2, x3] == 0}, 
    x3 == H]
      };` you get a closer to similar deformation for the different pressure NeumannValues.

Comment: Hmmm ... your alternative Dirichlet conditions are not what I want in my problem. Your alternative `bcD[[1]]` is far too restrictive at the bottom (total fix, e.g., you would glue the cylinder to a table) and `bcD[[2]]` forces `u1 = 0` and `u2 = 0` at the top. I was thinking of a cylinder under side pressure e.g. minding his own business standing freely on a table (only `u3 = 0` at the bottom). From a mechanical point of view, I expected the top to stay flat naturally. From an implementation point of view I have to be careful with `0 <= x3 <= H` in the Neumann values from now on.

Comment: @MauricioFernández, oh did not want to suggest that you change the BCs I just wanted to point out that there is an interplay between them. To be honest I was also surprised by the effect `<` vs v`<=` had.

Comment: @MauricioFernández, see update. The problem is that with <= you are also applying the NBC at the cabs. And with < it's not applied everywhere. Sorry it took me so long. I was thinking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Cool! Thanks, that looks mechanically a lot better. Could you also post the code for marking the boundary with `ElementMarker` such that `ElementMarker == 3` is used?

Comment: @MauricioFernández see update.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MauricioFernández, you are welcome! <\pressure=On>Now I want to see some papers mentioning the WL FEM<\pressure=OFF> ;-)

Comment: <\nervous laugh=On> ahahha alright alright <\nervous laugh=OFF> :D